# Andengine Modifier, do something on every step in path?

Tags: path, andengine, path-finding, modifier

I have Pathfinding with moving obstacles so Astar isn't quite the right way but I think what I need I can get to work if I can update a matrix in my TiledMap on every step the PathModifier takes.

Is that possible?

There is onModifierStarted and onModifierFinished but there seems to be no "onModifierMove"?

Answer (score 3):

I think you kind of answered your own question really - take 1 step, and then in the onModifierFinished, make your matrix adjustments, then setup the next PathModifier to move 1 more step ... rinse, repeat as needed

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about PathModifier but for other modifiers you can use onManageUpdate method like below:

```
sprite.registerEntityModifier(new MoveModifier(time, x1, x2, y1, y2){

    @Override
    protected void onModifierStarted(IEntity pItem) {
        super.onModifierStarted(pItem);

        //do somthing when modifier started
    }

    @Override
    protected void onModifierFinished(IEntity pItem) {
        super.onModifierFinished(pItem);

        //do somthing when modifier finished

    }

    @Override
        protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed, IEntity pItem) {
        super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed, pItem);

        //do somthing when modifier is running

    }

}));
```